# Как определить сворачивание окна в Windows?

Tags: c#, unity3d, windows

Ребят помогите, не могу найти

Как определить сворачивание или разворачивание окна в Windows?

Хочу, чтобы, если файлик сохранения перекидывали в папку там, то надо его подхватить, а для этого надо чекнуть когда окно свернулось и потом проверить...

Пс: немного не так сформулировал, как задетектить когда фокус на окне приложения пропадает или снова появляется?

Comment: Кто сказал, что для работы с файлами надо что-то сворачивать

Comment: Ну когда окно развёрнуто, а ты хочешь добавить сохранение, сворачиваешь и добавляешь, оно же должно его увидеть когда разворачиваешь обратно...

Comment: Ну окей, допустим файл там появился но при этом игра как то не сворачивалась... (разве так можно?) Как тогда проверить что сохра появилась?

Comment: Я наверно не правильно выразился немного, как задетектить что фокус на приложении пропал или вернулся?

Comment: Типичная проблема XY. Тут скорее следует мониторить состояние папки на предмет изменений. Файл может легко появиться без сворачивания или переключения фокуса с игры, например может быть заброшен туда через расшаренную сетевую папку с другого компьютера.

Comment: 1) Можно добавить кнопку "Обновить" в интерфейс 2) Под виндой можно использовать [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher)

Answer (score 1):

У MonoBehavior есть метод [OnApplicationFocus(bool)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html).
Можешь сделать синглтон и запихнуть в него такой код.

```
public class FocusChecker : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static FocusChecker _instance;
    public static bool IsFocused {get; private set;} = false;
    public static Action<bool> OnFocusChange;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance == this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
        _instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    private void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)
    {
        IsFocused = hasFocus;
        OnFocusChange?.Invoke(hasFocus);
    }
}
```

И потом просто обращаться к полю **PauseChecker.IsPaused**, если нужно узнать состояние, или к экшену **OnFocusChange**, если нужно поймать ивент

Comment: ещё и задизили ответ...

Comment: это костыль, по сути, хоть и сработает. А так https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher

Comment: @aepot ну он вроде в p.s. написал именно `"как задетектить когда фокус на окне приложения пропадает или снова появляется"`, так что я ответил именно на то, что он спросил. А так да, для того, чтобы отслеживать состояние папки ваш вариант подходит гораздо лучше.

Comment: Да, спасибо, буду использовать файл систем вотчер, но OnApplicationFocus мне тоже понадобится)